# How could keep the row position after refreshing in the RadGridView (WinForms)?

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

How could keep the row position after refreshing in the RadGridView by using WinForms? This is my source:

```
    private void myRadGridView_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space && CurrentCellIsCheckItem())
        {
            RadScrollBarElement vScrollBar = myRadGridView.TableElement.VScrollBar;
            int scrollBarValue = vScrollBar.Value;
            var saveRow = myRadGridView.CurrentRow;

            CheckItemChanged();

            myRadGridView.CurrentRow = saveRow;
            myRadGridView.TableElement.VScrollBar.Value = scrollBarValue;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you:

```
int rowIndex = radGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
...
radGridView1.CurrentRow = radGridView1.Rows[rowIndex];
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to have some unique row identifier e.g. ID, which you will save prior the refresh, and the after the refresh, iterate the rows and using the saved identifier find the needed row.

Your code is not working because you are saving a reference to the row, which reference is no longer valid after the refresh, as the rows are being recreated.